# Default Route in ip route

Tags: routing, dd-wrt

I'm trying to setup an IP based route in DD-WRT using DD-WRT v24-sp2 (12/22/14) giga.

Instead of only sending traffic from `10.13.37.0/24` to the `tun1` VPN, all traffic is going there.

Below is the output when I run `ip route`.  Can someone point me towards the right direction to have 10.13.37.0/24 traffic route to tun1 and the rest go to vlan2.

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.142.1.5 dev tun1 
10.13.37.0/24 dev br1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.13.37.1 
10.142.1.1 via 10.142.1.5 dev tun1 
10.142.1.5 dev tun1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.142.1.6 
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.142.1.5 dev tun1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.255.1 
173.52.198.0/24 dev vlan2  proto kernel  scope link  src 173.52.198.34 
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1 
209.222.18.67 via 173.52.198.1 dev vlan2
```

Comment: "traffic from 10.13.37.0/24 to the tun1 VPN" I guess you mean "traffic **to** 10.13.37.0/24". What sense is `0.0.0.0/1 via 10.142.1.5 dev tun1` supposed to make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration does not have a `default` route; that is the problem.

```
ip route add default via 173.52.198.1 dev vlan2
```

You can configure that permanently. Linux usually does that in `/etc/sysconfig/network/routes` but with DD-WRT that may be different.